# You must load or assign this property before you can read its value in case of getMimeContent() method

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-addins

I tried below case but getting same error.
**microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.local.ServiceObjectPropertyException: You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.**

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

case 1 :
Item itm2 =  Item.bind(service, new ItemId(itemId), PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
EmailMessage emailMessage2 = EmailMessage.bind(service, itm1.getId());
itm2.getMimeContent();

case 2 :

Item itm2 =  Item.bind(service, new ItemId(itemId), PropertySet.getFirstClassProperties());
EmailMessage emailMessage2 = EmailMessage.bind(service, itm1.getId());
itm2.getMimeContent();

But getting the same error again and again. I want Mine content so , can change in.eml format .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the property before you can access it.

Create a `PropertySet` and add `MIMEContent` as a property:

```
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
propSet.Add(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
```

Then add the `PropertySet` as an overload property for your `Bind` code:

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = EmailMessage.bind(service, itemId, propSet);
String content = emailMessage.getMimeContent().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is working for me properly and the overall code have written in answer.